# Lost reputation due to removed post

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, deleted-posts

Today I lost 25 reputation points and I'm just curious why? Apparently it was an upvoted and accepted answer and I thought that questions with answers can't be deleted easily. Talking about the general case, when a question gets removed by a Moderator, I'd think it'd be unfair to lose the points, because one still took the time to answer the question and probably invested a significant amount of work.

Unfortunately I don't have a link to the question. All I have is this:

> [image: screen shot]

but the "link" to the question is not clickable.

A syntax error question is a bad example for "probably invested a significant amount of work", I know, but again, I'm just curious what happened and want to know, why one does loose the reputation points ?

Comment: Do you have a link to the removed post? It might well be that the post was deemed unsuitable for SO.

Comment: "questions with answers can't be deleted easily" That depends, closed questions can be deleted easily by three (more if highly upvoted or with highly upvoted answers) trusted users regardless of whether they have (upvoted) answers.

Comment: `lost 25 reputation` , I assume the your accepted answer with one vote, That question got deleted now, that's why you lost 25 reputation, However there can be another reason as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [question was deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435611/you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-mysql/14436288) (+10k and OP only) by the community.

You had an answer on it that was upvoted once and accepted, which also got deleted.

When a post gets deleted, you lose/gain any reputation you gained/lost from it.

Comment: I don't want to whine about lost points, don't get me wrong, but in the future wouldn't it make sense to not remove the reputation points one earned by answering a question, regardless if it's removed later?

Comment: @tombon: If the question survives for 60 days, then you don't lose the reputation if you had a score of 3 or more.

Comment: @animuson That's a good rule, thanks for clarification.

Comment: A side question: As per new rule the OP can also see the deleted questions. Can a less than 10K user who has answered a question see that deleted question. e.g. can this OP ([tomborm](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/184827/tombom)) see [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435611/you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-mysql/14436288)?

Comment: @hims056 - No. They would have to be +10k for that.

Answer (score 2):

The entire question [You have an error in your SQL syntax - mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14435611/1288) was deleted.  It had been closed back in March as "too localized" since the problem was just a missing semicolon.

Comment: I don't want to whine about lost points, don't get me wrong, but in the future wouldn't it make sense to not remove the reputation points one earned by answering a question, regardless if it's removed later?

Comment: @tombom - Why would it make sense? If the post is gone, it was a question that is not suitable for the site. Would it make sense to keep reputation gained for answering questions that shouldn't be on the site?

Comment: @Oded Good point