# Reputation (and answer) lost on deleted question

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, specific-question, deleted-questions

Before I get to the main part of my question, I know something similar was asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178037/lost-reputation-due-to-removed-post), but I have a more localized question about a certain deleted question. If I need to, then I'll delete this.

I was told [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218207/lost-my-answer-on-deleted-question) that if one of my answers were deleted, then I could ask on here on Meta for someone with more than 10k to retrieve it. Instead of retrieving my answer, though, I was wondering why [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591635/how-do-i-swap-images-for-buttons/21591701) was deleted.

The last I saw after I had answered it, I had one upvote and the question only had one downvote. Now the question wasn't the best in the world, but at least it didn't have [22 downvotes and a score of -20] [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448244/please-tell-what-is-the-wrong-in-this-code).

So my question is, if someone wouldn't mind answering, why was the question (along with my answer and earned reputation) deleted? I know this is a very specific question, so if I need to I'll be more than happy to delete this question (unless someone with an upvoted answer doesn't want me to)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The author of the question deleted their account. Since, at the time of deletion, the question had a score of -4 and was closed, it was automatically deleted by the Community user along with the user.